# Qual a melhor técnica para usar ViewModel com listas mvc C#?

Tags: c#, mvc, lista, viewmodel, model

Eu tenho dois modelos: pacote de inscrição do evento e pacote de inscrição, onde o modelo pacote de inscrição do evento possui uma lista de pacotes de inscrições (veja no código abaixo, retirei alguns campos).

```
//Model
public class PacoteInscricaoEvento
{
    public PacoteInscricaoEvento()
    {
        PacoteIncricao = new List<PacoteIncricao>();
    }
    public int PacoteInscricaoEventoId { get; set; }
    public short Nrvagas { get; set; }       
    public IList<PacoteIncricao> PacoteIncricao { get; set; }
}

public class PacoteIncricao
{
    public int PacoteIncricaoId { get; set; }
    public string NmpacoteIncricao { get; set; }
}
```

Logo, criei duas views models, uma para cada modelo (código abaixo), dentre outros métodos  implementa os métodos abstratos copiar view e copiar model da classe abstrata ViewModel para facilitar o processo de conversão entre a view model para model e vice-versa.

```
public class PacoteInscricaoEventoViewModel : ViewModel<PacoteInscricaoEventoViewModel, PacoteInscricaoEvento>
{
    public PacoteInscricaoEventoViewModel()
    {
        PacoteIncricaoViewModel = new List<PacoteIncricaoViewModel>();    
    }

    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    public int PacoteInscricaoEventoId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nº de Vagas")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public short Nrvagas { get; set; }
    public List<PacoteIncricaoViewModel> PacoteIncricaoViewModel { get; set; }
    public override PacoteInscricaoEvento CopiarModelo(PacoteInscricaoEvento modelo)
    {
        int indiceElemento = 0;
        modelo.PacoteInscricaoEventoId = this.PacoteInscricaoEventoId;
        modelo.Nrvagas = this.Nrvagas;
        //listas
        //Excluindo os pacotes que foram exluidos na viewmodel no modelo
        if (modelo.PacoteIncricao != null && modelo.PacoteIncricao.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (PacoteIncricao pacoteIncricaoModelo in modelo.PacoteIncricao)
            {
                //buscando o indice na view model
                indiceElemento = this.PacoteIncricaoViewModel.FindIndex(x => x.PacoteIncricaoId == pacoteIncricaoModelo.PacoteIncricaoId);
                if (indiceElemento == -1)
                    modelo.PacoteIncricao.Remove(pacoteIncricaoModelo);//se nao encontrar exclui
            }
        }
        //adcionando ou alterando os elementos nas view models
        if (this.PacoteIncricaoViewModel != null && this.PacoteIncricaoViewModel.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (PacoteIncricaoViewModel pacoteInscricaoVM in this.PacoteIncricaoViewModel)
            {
                //buscando o indice no modelo
                indiceElemento = modelo.PacoteIncricao.ToList().FindIndex(x => x.PacoteIncricaoId == pacoteInscricaoVM.PacoteIncricaoId);
                if (indiceElemento == -1) //se nao encontrou altera
                    modelo.PacoteIncricao.Add(pacoteInscricaoVM.CopiarModelo(new PacoteIncricao()));
                else //senao altera o elemento
                    pacoteInscricaoVM.CopiarModelo(modelo.PacoteIncricao[indiceElemento]);
            }
        }
        return modelo;
    }
    public override PacoteInscricaoEventoViewModel CopiarView(PacoteInscricaoEvento modelo)
    {
        this.PacoteInscricaoEventoId = modelo.PacoteInscricaoEventoId;
        this.Nrvagas = modelo.Nrvagas;
        //listas
        foreach (PacoteIncricao pacoteinscricaotmp in modelo.PacoteIncricao)
        {
            this.PacoteIncricaoViewModel.Add(new PacoteIncricaoViewModel().CopiarView(pacoteinscricaotmp));
        }
        return this;
    }
}

public class PacoteIncricaoViewModel : ViewModel<PacoteIncricaoViewModel, PacoteIncricao>
{  
    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    public int PacoteIncricaoId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nome Pacote")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string NmpacoteIncricao { get; set; }             
    public override PacoteIncricao CopiarModelo(PacoteIncricao modelo)
    {
        modelo.PacoteIncricaoId = this.PacoteIncricaoId;
        modelo.NmpacoteIncricao = this.NmpacoteIncricao;
        return modelo;
    }   
    public override PacoteIncricaoViewModel CopiarView(PacoteIncricao modelo)
    {
        this.PacoteIncricaoId = modelo.PacoteIncricaoId;
        this.NmpacoteIncricao = modelo.NmpacoteIncricao;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Desse modo, qual a melhor técnica (ou exemplos de códigos) para criar views models que contenham views models nesta situação(listas), sem usar o automapper ou similares?
Obrigado

Comment: Cara, usa AutoMapper: http://automapper.org/, vai mudar a sua vida. Amanhã posto um exemplo para você.

Comment: Cara, eu tentei usar ele um PJ que estou escrevendo e deu um monte pau, com as referências no entity framework 7 na hora de editar os dados(editar). Era como se o entity não tratasse o dados convertidos pelo auto mapper vindo das views como os mesmos, perdendo suas referências, quando excluía um item de uma lista como pacote  de inscrição por exemplo na VM e adicionasse outros, o entity persistia os novos e trazia os excluídos novamente, dai  tinha que fazer um monte de coisa acabei desistindo man.☹️

Comment: Man, pelo seu código eu vejo alguns problemas de responsabilidade do view model, para que serve o método `CopiarModelo`? O AutoMapper te entrega o objeto pronto para você mandar para o Serviço por exemplo ou o contrário, pega um DTO e transforma em um view model. Ele faz isso de maneira bem simples, basta que os nomes das propriedades sejam os mesmos, no caso de serem diferentes você pode criar uma factory que faz essa conversão para você.

Comment: O copiar serve examente para fazer o processo que o auto mapper faz que é converter o dado. Pois está dando um monte pau no entity framework 7 na hora de editar o objeto.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse exemplo: https://gist.github.com/paulodiogo/c413d3ead2dfc58feda9a7a139e2578a

Comment: No caso do entity framework, como que você está fazendo? Você recebe a entidade direto da view? Não seria melhor ler a entidade do banco e altera-la com os dados que está recebendo da view?

Comment: Pô Paulo eu vou dar uma olhada no código que você postou pra mim meu nego. Eu fiZ assim sem pegar a direito no banco na views q preditor fazer um contrato já que todas a views irão fazer a mesma coisa ( substituindo ao auto mapper, que gostaria muito que funcionasse comigo)

Comment: Você manda o objeto que é gerado direto para o banco?

Comment: Vou vê se eu coloco um trecho do código no Github e te passo o link, mas já tirei o automapper. Pode ser?

Comment: coloca lá e me manda...